# Moving Jira Server to https - gadgets and app search no longer working

Tags: apache, https, jira

I have recently moved our Jira Server installation to an https URL - we have a reverse proxy setup and I have configured apache/Jira according to atlassian's docs. https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/securing-your-atlassian-applications-with-apache-using-ssl-838284349.html

We can access and use Jira with no issues, however the activity feed on the dashboard, and the search function to find new apps is no longer working.

When i look at the console it still appears to be trying to access the http:// version of the URL even though I have updated the base URL to the https version.

When I view source, I can see several references to the old http:// version of the URL. e.g.

```
WRM._unparsedData["com.atlassian.servicedesk.core-ui:util-base-url.base-url"]="\"http://jira.xxx.xxx\"";

<input type="hidden" id="upmBaseUrl" name="upmBaseUrl" value="http://jira.xxx.xxx">

<input type="hidden" value="http://jira.xxx.xxx/plugins/servlet/upm/marketplace" name="upmUriMarketplace" id="upmUriMarketplace">
```

Is there some other place where this needs to be updated? I've tried a general search/replace in the database, and i've grepped the installation and application data directories for the old URL.

Could it be a cache issue?

Answer (score 0):

To move the Jira site to a new HTTPS location, you generally need to ensure that you have configured both:

1. the [base URL](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/configuring-the-base-url-938847830.html), and
2. the proxyName, proxyPort, secure, and the **scheme** in the `<Connector>` of Jira's [conf/server.xml](https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/securing-your-atlassian-applications-with-apache-using-ssl-838284349.html). Also ensure that you're editing the correct `<Connector>` (since there are multiple in the default install, some of which are commented out).

You mentioned that you have done both of these, but the symptoms suggest that either #1 or #2 might not be complete or 100% correct.

If you are using a containerized version of Jira, also make sure that any environment variables also correspond to your new setup, since these can override settings in the above places.

For example, if you are using the [official Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/atlassian/jira-software), this means variables such as `ATL_TOMCAT_SCHEME`, `ATL_TOMCAT_SECURE` and the like.